# Visual Studio App Center Analytics Not working for Xamarin Forms Android Project

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-app-center

I am using **Visual Studio App Center** for my Xamarin Forms Android Application for capturing the Analytics(Events and Crashes)

I am configuring crashes and analytics in **OnStart** of my **App.Xaml.cs**

```
AppCenter.Start($"android={Settings.Current.AppCenterAnalyticsAndroid};" +
typeof(Analytics), typeof(Crashes));
```

And for invoking the Events I am calling the below Method.

```
public void TrackEvent(string name, Dictionary<string, string> properties = null)
{
       Analytics.SetEnabledAsync(true).ConfigureAwait(false);
       Analytics.TrackEvent(name, properties);
}
```

Crashes are logging correctly in **App Center** But the events are not.
Also I can see the corresponding entries in **Log Flow**

Comment: Just a wild guess, but from the docs: "Also, there is a maximum limit of 256 characters per event name and 125 characters per event property name and event property value." Maybe this is happening?

Comment: I am only passing status keys like this "Status confirm Page :: Dismiss pop up "

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your app secret string is invalid because it contains `+ typeof(Analytics)`, it should be `, typeof(Analytics)`.

Since you used the android key/value delimiter we could extract the appSecret and make it work with Crashes, but `typeof(Analytics)` ended up in the wrong appSecret parameter string.

Comment: This is great. Thanks for figuring it out :)

Comment: Yep, this was an allusive one. Thank you.

Comment: Excellent pickup. I was in the exact same position after deleting one of the unnecessary keys. I have been pulling my hair for a couple of hours as to why this wasn't doing a thing.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to add  `Analytics.SetEnabledAsync(true).ConfigureAwait(false);`

Simply Call `Analytics.TrackEvent(name, properties);` (it doesn't need to be in a task anyways. I track my events in the Construtor of pages, for example.

Also, when you run the application, you get a debug Message confirming that AppCenter has been configured correctly, check if that is the case.

And, it may take a while, for them to appear in the Events.

Comment: even without this line "Analytics.SetEnabledAsync(true).ConfigureAwait(false);" it is not working. I saw this statement in console "Analytics needs to be started before it can be used." That is the reason i add the code.

Comment: You don't need SetEnabled as the default value is true, the problem is something else.